# Onchange 2 fields in JavaScript widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo

I need to use onchange function in JavaScript widget

I have two fields in a JavaScript widget
 - 1st(account which refer to contracts) and
 - 2nd (task which refer to customers)  and i want to use onchange
   between them

I want to change account field based on task field, that when I choose  customer it should load only contracts of that customer only.

Anyone face that before? could you give me examples?

[image: Here is the photo i have 2 fields in that line]

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
openerp.net2do_elkamel = function (instance) {

    var module = instance.hr_timesheet_sheet

    module.WeeklyTimesheet = module.WeeklyTimesheet.extend({
        events: {
            "click .oe_timesheet_weekly_account a": "go_to",
            "click .oe_timesheet_weekly_task a": "go_to_partner",
        },
        go_to_partner: function (event) {
            var id = JSON.parse($(event.target).data("cus-id"));
            this.do_action({
                type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                res_model: "res.partner",
                res_id: id,
                views: [[false, 'form']],
                target: 'current'
            });
        },
        initialize_content: function () {
            var self = this;
            if (self.setting)
                return;
            // don't render anything until we have date_to and date_from
            if (!self.get("date_to") || !self.get("date_from"))
                return;
            this.destroy_content();

            // it's important to use those vars to avoid race conditions
            var dates;
            var accounts;
            var account_names;
            var task_names;
            var default_get;
            return this.render_drop.add(new instance.web.Model("hr.analytic.timesheet").call("default_get", [
                ['account_id', 'customer', 'general_account_id', 'journal_id', 'date', 'name', 'user_id', 'product_id', 'product_uom_id', 'to_invoice', 'amount', 'unit_amount'],
                new instance.web.CompoundContext({'user_id': self.get('user_id')})]).then(function (result) {
                default_get = result;
                // calculating dates
                dates = [];
                var start = self.get("date_from");
                var end = self.get("date_to");
                while (start <= end) {
                    dates.push(start);
                    start = start.clone().addDays(1);
                }

                timesheet_lines = _(self.get("sheets")).chain()
                    .map(function (el) {
                        // much simpler to use only the id in all cases
                        if (typeof(el.account_id) === "object")
                            el.account_id = el.account_id[0];
                        if (typeof(el.customer) === "object")
                            el.customer = el.customer[0];
                        return el;
                    }).value();

                // group by account
                var timesheet_lines_by_account_id = _.groupBy(timesheet_lines, function (el) {
                    return el.account_id;
                });

                // group by account and customer
                var timesheet_lines_by_account_id_task_id = _.groupBy(timesheet_lines, function (el) {
                    return [el.account_id, el.customer];
                });

                var account_ids = _.map(_.keys(timesheet_lines_by_account_id), function (el) {
                    return el === "false" ? false : Number(el)
                });

                return new instance.web.Model("hr.analytic.timesheet").call("multi_on_change_account_id", [[], account_ids,
                    new instance.web.CompoundContext({'user_id': self.get('user_id')})]).then(function (accounts_defaults) {
                    accounts = _(timesheet_lines_by_account_id_task_id).chain().map(function (lines, account_id_task_id) {
                        account_defaults = _.extend({}, default_get, (accounts_defaults[lines[0].account_id] || {}).value || {});
                        // group by days
                        var index = _.groupBy(lines, "date");
                        var days = _.map(dates, function (date) {
                            var day = {day: date, lines: index[instance.web.date_to_str(date)] || []};
                            // add line where we will insert/remove hours
                            var to_add = _.find(day.lines, function (line) {
                                return line.name === self.description_line
                            });
                            if (to_add) {
                                day.lines = _.without(day.lines, to_add);
                                day.lines.unshift(to_add);
                            } else {
                                day.lines.unshift(_.extend(_.clone(account_defaults), {
                                    name: self.description_line,
                                    unit_amount: 0,
                                    date: instance.web.date_to_str(date),
                                    account_id: lines[0].account_id,
                                    customer: lines[0].customer,
                                }));
                            }
                            return day;
                        });
                        return {
                            account_task: account_id_task_id,
                            account: lines[0].account_id,
                            task: lines[0].customer,
                            days: days,
                            account_defaults: account_defaults
                        };
                    }).value();

                    // we need the name_get of the analytic accounts
                    return new instance.web.Model("account.analytic.account").call("name_get", [_.pluck(accounts, "account"),
                        new instance.web.CompoundContext()]).then(function (result) {
                        account_names = {};
                        _.each(result, function (el) {
                            account_names[el[0]] = el[1];
                        });
                        // we need the name_get of the customer
                        return new instance.web.Model("res.partner").call("name_get", [_(accounts).chain().pluck("task").filter(function (el) {
                            return el;
                        }).value(),
                            new instance.web.CompoundContext()]).then(function (result) {
                            task_names = {};
                            _.each(result, function (el) {
                                task_names[el[0]] = el[1];
                            });
                            accounts = _.sortBy(accounts, function (el) {
                                return account_names[el.account];
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            })).then(function (result) {
                // we put all the gathered data in self, then we render
                self.dates = dates;
                self.accounts = accounts;
                self.account_names = account_names;
                self.task_names = task_names;
                self.default_get = default_get;
                //real rendering
                self.display_data();
            });
        },
        init_add_account: function () {
            var self = this;
            if (self.dfm)
                return;
            self.$(".oe_timesheet_weekly_add_row").show();
            self.dfm = new instance.web.form.DefaultFieldManager(self);
            self.dfm.extend_field_desc({
                account: {
                    relation: "account.analytic.account",
                },
                task: {
                    relation: "res.partner",
                },
            });
            self.task_m2o = new instance.web.form.FieldMany2One(self.dfm, {
                attrs: {
                    name: "task",
                    type: "many2one",
                    modifiers: '{"required": true}',
                },
            });


            self.account_m2o = new instance.web.form.FieldMany2One(self.dfm, {

                attrs: {
                    name: "account",
                    type: "many2one",
                    domain: [
                        ['type', 'in', ['normal', 'contract']],
                        ['use_timesheets', '=', 1],
                    ],
                    widget:"selection",

                    context: {
                        default_use_timesheets: 1,
                        default_type: "contract",
                        default_partner_id:self.task_m2o.value,
                    },
                    modifiers: '{"required": true}',
                },
            });


            self.task_m2o.prependTo(self.$(".oe_timesheet_weekly_add_row td"));
            self.account_m2o.prependTo(self.$(".oe_timesheet_weekly_add_row td"));

            self.account_m2o.$input.focusout(function () {
                var account_id = self.account_m2o.get_value();
                if (account_id === false) {
                    return;
                }
                self.task_m2o.init(self.dfm, {
                    attrs: {
                        name: "task",
                        type: "many2one",
                        context: {
                            'account_id': account_id,
                        },
                    },
                });
                // reset value previously selected
                self.task_m2o.set_value(false);
                self.task_m2o.render_value();
            });

            self.$(".oe_timesheet_weekly_add_row button").click(function () {
                var id = self.account_m2o.get_value();
                if (id === false) {
                    self.dfm.set({display_invalid_fields: true});
                    return;
                }
                var ops = self.generate_o2m_value();
                new instance.web.Model("hr.analytic.timesheet").call("on_change_account_id", [[], id]).then(function (res) {
                    var def = _.extend({}, self.default_get, res.value, {
                        name: self.description_line,
                        unit_amount: 0,
                        date: instance.web.date_to_str(self.dates[0]),
                        account_id: id,
                        customer: self.task_m2o.get_value(),
                    });
                    ops.push(def);
                    self.set({"sheets": ops});
                });
            });
        },

        get_box: function (account, day_count) {
            return this.$('[data-account-task="' + account.account_task + '"][data-day-count="' + day_count + '"]');
        },
        get_total: function (account) {
            return this.$('[data-account-task-total="' + account.account_task + '"]');
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: Why does the question title start with the word "Solved"?  Won't that just dissuade people from coming here to answer it?

Comment: because i solve it myself :D

Comment: Ah, I see.  :-)  It would be helpful if you either deleted the question, or if you think your solution would be useful to others, posted it here. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question.

Comment: @MostafaMohamed You should answer your own question and accept your answer.

Comment: @Mostafa Mohamed, your solution can fix the issue to another people; just like me for example.

Comment: ok i i will add it i promise :)